# Workflow Assigned To Dynamic User?

Tags: workflow, state-machine

I created State Machine workflow, in Workflow Initiation Form having Owner Field. Once start workflow task assigned to Owner (Dynamic User)?

Comment: Is it a Visual Studio workflow, or a SharePoint Designer one?

Comment: Visual Studio workflow